# Error Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() en proyecto PHP y IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, iis

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado en PHP (CodeIgniter), el proyecto tiene una conexión a MySQL y otra a SQLSERVER y esta funcionando bien de forma local. Para realizar la conexión a SQLSERVER tuve que instalar ODBC y descargar 2 archivos .dll (*php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll* y *php_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll*) para posteriormente colocarlos en la carpeta de ext. en el directorio de PHP y finalmente modificar el archivo php.ini para llamar a los drivers.

Tengo la tarea de subir el proyecto a un Windows server. Para subir el proyecto instale php, mysql, instale los drivers (.dll) tal cual lo hice en local y posteriormente subí el proyecto a wwwroot. Realice pruebas para validar su funcionalidad, los módulos que conectan con MySQL funcionan sin problema, pero los módulos que tiene conexión a SQLSERVER me están mandando el siguiente error ***Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()***, ya cambien los .dll y el error sigue. Cheque el phpinfo y veo que no esta instalado el pdo_sqlsrv.

> PHPINFO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Archivos .dll

**php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll**

**php_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll**

Podrían apoyarme dándome ideas de cómo solucionar el error.

Saludos y que tengan un excelente miércoles.

Comment: Lo que tienes instalado es una extensión para conectar a SQL Server con PDO, no con `sqlsrv_*()`. Revisa la documentación de [PDO para SQL Server](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php)

Comment: Es que esos movimientos no los realice en local, de echo le moví al servidor lo que hice en local, pero me marcan error los módulos que tienen conexión con sqlserver.

Comment: ¿Reiniciaste el servidor después de instalar las extensiones?

Comment: Sipi, pero nada. No me reconoce el phpinfo los dll

Comment: Sigue las instrucciones del sitio oficial de Microsoft [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php) y [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Es que según yo le hice así pero no quiere jalar, entonces lo realice de otra forma y me manda un error diferente mira, segun creo que ya se instalaron los dll pero ahora ya no se hace la conexion mysql y antes si estaba bien  mysqli::real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]